# Expose database to deployment on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a deployment running a pod that needs access to a postgres database I am running in the same cluster as the kubernetes cluster. How do I create a service that selects the deployment such that it has access. My pods keep restarting as the connection times out. I have created firewall rules in the vpc subnet to allow internal communication and have modified pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf
My deployment definition is given below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  labels: 
    name: server
    app: api
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: gcr.io/api:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: DB_HOSTNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: api-config
                  key: hostname
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: api-config
                  key: username
            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: api-config
                  key: name
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: api-config
                  key: password
```

This is my service definition to expose the database but I don't think I am selecting the deployment. I have followed the example [here](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services.html).

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
  label:
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.0.0.50
    ports:
      - port: 5432
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understand. You database is inside the cluster and you want to access it from the outside? Or is it the other way around (the database is outside the cluster)?

Comment: it is outside the kubernetes cluster but within the same vpc but I want to access it from within the cluster

Comment: did you try to connect with the ip or with service name?
Can you show us your connection string? Also, can you connect to the database using the external ip?

Comment: user=postgres password=password dbname=test host=postgres.c.kube-cluster.internal; I am using the gcp instance name, this gets resolved properly to the internal IP

Comment: @driftavalii, I have reviewed all the scenario on this [Exp.](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services.html) and it does not seem to match the question. Could you confirm if the Postgres DB is indeed outside of the Cluster or within the Cluster?  Normally the DB deployment should be exposed using the [ClusterIP service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#creating-a-service) to enable internal communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to expose database to deployment on GKE:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment name-of-db --type=LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 8080
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This would be exposing the deployment which is not what I want, I want the pods in the deployment to access a database outside the cluster

Comment: Since you can hit the [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-clusterip) from a pod in the cluster, the deployment should be exposed using the ClusterIP.